# Why I only get the last output in my output file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to find particular columns based on a list of column's name by using pandas in python 2.7. For example,

```
>>>df = pd.read_csv('database.csv') 
A,B,C,D,E,F,G  # A to G columns in database
1,2,3,4,5,6,7  

>>>name_list = pd.read_csv('column_name.csv') 
Name # 'Name' is set as index 
B    #  I need B, E and F column
E
F

# code used to select particular columns
result = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    if col in name_list.index:
        result = df[[col]]  # select column based on the given list


result.to_csv('result.csv')  # write my result to csv file
```

The `print result` is fine, I can see column B, E and F, however, the result.csv file only has the last output (column F)? I have tried to move `result.to_csv` to different positions but it was still the same.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You are overwriting result everytime, also you don't need to loop just pass a list to df to select those columns: `df[name_list.index]` should work

Answer (score 3):

You overwrite `result` every time hence the reason you only get the last result, also you don't need to use a loop this will work:

```
df[name_list.index].to_csv('result.csv')
```

Example:

```
In [21]:

import pandas as pd
import io
temp="""A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,6,7"""
temp1="""Name
B
E
F"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
print(df)
name = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), index_col=[0])
name
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
Out[21]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [B, E, F]
In [20]:

df[name.index]
Out[20]:
   B  E  F
0  2  5  6
```

The above shows that it's not necessary to create another df just to get the columns of interest to write out, once you read in your names you can pass the index to sub-select the columns of interest from the original df and then write them out to a csv.

**EDIT**

If you have duplicated entries in your index you can call [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.Index.unique) to de-duplicate the values:

```
In [24]:

temp1="""Name
B
B
E
F"""
name = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), index_col=[0])
print(name)
df[name.index.unique()]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [B, B, E, F]
Out[24]:
   B  E  F
0  2  5  6
```

Comment: Sorted, thanks. I have tested your code and it can work. However if I have duplicated name_list, for example, I have two 'column B' in my name_list, I found the duplicated column would be written in my result as well. How could I solve this issue? Thanks,

Comment: The `index.unique()` could be found here ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.Index.unique )