# How to improve the code with more elegant way and low memory consumed?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset which the dimension is around 2,000 (rows) x 120,000 (columns).

And I'd like to pick up certain columns (~8,000 columns).

So the file dimension would be 2,000 (rows) x 8,000 (columns).

Here is the code written by a good man (I searched from stackoverflow but I am sorry I have forgotten his name).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('...mydata.csv') 

my_query = pd.read_csv('...myquery.csv')

df[list['Name'].unique()].to_csv('output.csv')
```

However, the result shows **MemoryError** in my console, which means the code may not work quite well.

So does anyone know how to improve the code with more efficient way to select the certain columns?

Comment: Why don't you just do `df[list['Query.Name'].unique()].to_csv('output.csv')` the `name_list` line seems superfluous to me, also using `list` for a variable name is not a good idea as this will shadow the `list` python type

Comment: Which line is the Memory Error occuring on ? (where is the -> pointing at in the traceback?) Also are you using 64 bit python? This can help a lot with memory errors.

Comment: It would also be useful to know which kind of data this is. Strings, floats, mixed content?

Comment: @maxymoo  Thanks, second line, df=pd.read_csv....., I used 32bit.

Comment: @chris-sc mixed content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865860/why-i-only-get-the-last-output-in-my-output-file).

So, my solution use `read_csv` with arguments:

1. `iterator=True` - if True, return a `TextFileReader` to enable reading a file into memory piece by piece
2. `chunksize=1000` - an number of rows to be used to “chunk” a file into pieces. Will cause an `TextFileReader` object to be returned
3. `usecols=subset` -  a subset of columns to return, results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table).

I filter large dataset with `usecols` - I use only dataset (2 000, 8 000) instead (2 000, 120 000).

```
import pandas as pd

#read subset from csv and remove duplicate indices
subset = pd.read_csv('8kx1.csv', index_col=[0]).index.unique()
print subset

#use subset as filter of columns
tp = pd.read_csv('input.csv',iterator=True, chunksize=1000, usecols=subset) 
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)

print df.head()
print df.shape

#write to csv 
df.to_csv('output.csv',iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
```

I use this snippet for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""A,B,C,D,E,F,G
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7"""

temp1=u"""Name
B
B
C
B
C
C
E
F"""

subset = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), index_col=[0]).index.unique()
print subset

#use subset as filter of columns
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), usecols=subset)

print df.head()
print df.shape
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and I have tested it. The console showed that I have to add `low_memory=False` to the command, then the code can work well in the linux environment very efficiently (but not work well in my laptop, I guess it is my spec issue, anyway, thanks a lot)!